# Does Rabbit MQ provide SOAP API's?

Tags: soap, rabbitmq

Does RabbitMQ provide SOAP Api's ?

I know it provides [Restful API's](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html)

I tried searching for it but could not get anything fruitful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: One possibility is to manage the SOAP over AMPQ, if it is acceptable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does RabbitMQ provide SOAP Api's ?

no

Comment: should it?  HELL NO! :)